# RSA implementation in Octave

Tags: algorithm, encryption, rsa, octave

I'm trying to implement a simple RSA calculation example in Octave, but I've got a problem when using p and q larger than 9900 (primes).
I suspect that it's because of the number size limit in Octave?

Is there another approach I can try? Thanks

I'm using this algorithm to generate the keys:

```
function [n,Phi,d,e] = rsa (p,q)
x=2;i=1;
n=p*q;                           %to calculate n
Phi=(p-1)*(q-1);                 %to calculate Phi

e=(Phi/4);
while x > 1
    e--;                        %to calculate e (I know it should be random)
    x = gcd(Phi, e);
end

val1=0;
d=Phi-e;
while(val1!=1);
    d--;                        %to calculate d (this is really nasty way, anyone can help?)
    val1=mod(d*e,Phi);
end
endfunction
```

and then I read the message, encode it to ASCII and encrypt it by

```
function result = modexp (base, exponent, modulus)
result = 1;
base = mod(base, modulus);
    while (exponent > 0)
        if (mod(exponent, 2) == 1)
           result =  mod((result * base) ,modulus);
        end
       exponent = bitshift(exponent,-1);
        base = mod((base * base) ,modulus);
    end
endfunction
```

by calling

```
Msg = toascii(Msg,x); %my function to convert message to ASCII

for j= 1:x
   cipher(j)= modexp(Msg(j),e,n);    %message encryption
end

display(cipher);

for j= 1:x
   message(j)= modexp(cipher(j),d,n);  %message decryption
end

display(message)
```

As I said, this code fails for p and q larger than 9900.

Any help will be much appreciated, thanks.

PS: entire code can be found here:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/20809963/rsa.m
but it's written in czech language.

Comment: What parts of that code are failing? It seems your key generation contains non-modular multiplication `mod(d*e,Phi)` in a loop.

Comment: Well, the code works, just not for large p and q, I would like it to work with larger numbers.

Comment: Again *where* and *how* does it fail? "The code does not work" and "the code fails" are not very comprehensive error messages, I hope you agree on that.

Comment: Sorry, I think the problem is in encryption/decryption algorithm, I think the calculation overflows ... it is really difficult to debug the code in Octave :3 The key is generated fine (but slowly, because of the algorithm used) encrypted message looks ok (but I suspect its not) and decryption just fails (when converted back from ASCII it's wrong)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I rewritten the generating code, now it works with larger numbers (p and q up to ~45000)

```
function [n,Phi,d,e] = rsa (p,q)
x=2;i=1;
n=0;Phi=0;e=0;d=0;
n=uint64(n); Phi=uint64(Phi); d=uint64(d); e=uint64(e);

n=p*q;
Phi=(p-1)*(q-1);

e = input('e:');

if(gcd(Phi,e) > 1)
    while gcd(Phi, e) > 1
        if(e<=2)
            e = Phi/4;
        else 
            e--;
        end
    end
    printf('e = %i', e);
end

if gcd(e,Phi) ~= 1
    error('d can't be calculated')
end
    [c,a,b] = gcd(e,Phi);
    d = mod(a,Phi); 
endfunction
```

The rest of the code is similar, I'm just casting everything to uint64 :)

My code is placed here, if anyone wants to try it https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/20809963/rsa.m